# jLabel slideshow when a mouse enters a button

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, slideshow, thread-sleep

I can't get this to work:

```
public void ru() throws InterruptedException {
    jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adv/room.jpg")));
    setVisible(true);
    Thread.sleep(400);
    jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adv/ROOMS.jpg")));
    setVisible(true);
    Thread.sleep(400);
    jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adv/background.jpg")));
    setVisible(true);
}

private void BtnRoomsMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    try {
        ru();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

Any solutions?
I want a jLabel to show a slide show when a mouse enters a certain button and stays like that as long as the mouse is still in a button. If the mouse happens to exit the button, the jlabel will return to a null state. (no more anything.) Is that possible? Please help. I also tried using `for` statement but no good. I'm using netbeans by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to implement a `javax.swing.Timer`. Trying to call `Thread.sleep()` will block the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Here is the basic construct

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

where `delay` is the time in milliseconds you want delayed and the `listener` will listen for the `Timer` `ActionEvent` fired every `delay` milliseconds.

So you want something like this

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   private Timer timer = null;
   ImageIcon[] icons = new ImageIcon[3];
   int index = -1;

   public MyFrame() {
       initComponents();
       icons[0] = new ImageIcon(...);
       icons[1] = new ImageIcon(...);
       icons[2] = new ImageIcon(...);

       timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (index + 1 > 2) {
                   index = 0;
                   jLabel3.setIcon(icons[index]);
               } else {
                   index++;
                   jLabel3.setIcon(icons[index]);
               }
           }
       });
   }
}
```

For your button, you need to use `mouseEntered` *and* `mouseExited`, then you can just call `timer.start()` or `timer.stop()`

```
private void jButton1MouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    timer.stop();
}

private void jButton1MouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    timer.start();
}
```

If you don't know how to add the `MouseListener` just right click on the button from the design view and select `Event -> Mouse -> mouseEntered`. Do the same for `mouseExited`.  You should see the above methods auto-generated for you.

---

**UPDATE**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ImageViewer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Timer timer = null;
    ImageIcon[] icons = new ImageIcon[5];
    int index = -1;

    public ImageViewer() {
        initComponents();
        try {

            icons[0] = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png"));
            icons[1] = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/caribbean-blue/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png"));
            icons[2] = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/royal-blue/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png"));
            icons[3] = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/moth-green/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png"));
            icons[4] = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/soylent-red/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (index + 1 > 4) {
                    index = 0;
                    jLabel1.setIcon(icons[index]);
                } else {
                    index++;
                    jLabel1.setIcon(icons[index]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new JButton();
        jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseExited(evt);
            }
        });

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(127, 127, 127))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 285, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 321, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(16, 16, 16))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1MouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        timer.start();
    }                                     

    private void jButton1MouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        timer.stop();
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ImageViewer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private JButton jButton1;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I'm near on getting it now. However, what should I put on `ImageIcon(..)?`

Comment: BTW, thanks peeskillet. You're saving my butt everytime I have a question. :D

Comment: Are you _serious_? You have the answer right in _front of you_!

Comment: Err.. What I mean is should I make it like this? `ImageIcon("/adv/back.jpg")`. Sorry :)

Comment: Do it exactly like your post. make sure `adv` is in the `src`

Comment: Should it be really in that folder? What if I've put it somewhere else? Well, I'll just do what you've said.

Comment: Yeah. It's not working. Something to do with Timer import and more

Comment: Did you use getClass().getResource() like in your post?

Comment: Hit `SHIFT + CTRL + I` to resolve all imports. Make sure you're importing `javax.swing.Timer` and not `java.util.Timer`

Comment: Ok.. Only 3 problems more. The timer constructor and `initComponents();` and invalid variable `timer`

Comment: Make sure you have the `timer` variable. I just edited. I was mssing it

Comment: Then? for the `initComponent` ? Should I create a new method?

Comment: I spelled it wrong. You should not have even touched yours. It was just a reference point in my code.

Comment: I've already changed that. However, there's still an error on that `initComponent`

Comment: There's another error. I can't call `timer` on my `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`

Comment: I'm going to try it. If i use this same code, and it works, I'm gonna go kill myself

Comment: Err.. I tried to remove the class that I have created earlier. The `timer` goes back. However, the same error as before. I can't call it

Comment: I tried to type it like this `timer.start();` It doesn't have any errors like it does before. However, when I tried running it, errors come out.

Comment: Ok I'm going to drown myself in the bath tub now. Whatever you are doing wrong, it has nothing to do with my code. Whatever problem you're facing it is unrelated. As I told you before and I will tell you again. Go over Java basics. Don't start trying to build Swing apps with gui builder before you even know how to hand code. All I'm going to say. Test my program. Look over everything I've said. If it still doesn't work. Ask another question. Because Everything I've told you works fine for me. Test my program. You don't need images, I have taken them from the web.

Comment: You really need to know where this frustration comes from. No one is here to hold anyone else's hand.When a user has no idea what they're doing, it's frustrating. We answer specific questions. You're lucky I'm one of the more patient ones that will even go this far. Other's will just link you a tutorial and tell you to learn yourself.

Comment: If only I have the time to do all that.
I hate to say that professors here teach us VB then will require us to make a program on java.
Thanks for helping me as always. I'll try to fix this one later.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `MouseAdapter` to the `JLabel` and use its `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` as follows:

```
        jLabel3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                   @Override
                   public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {      
                   try {
                        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adv/room.jpg")));
                        setVisible(true);
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adv/ROOMS.jpg")));
                        setVisible(true);
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/adv/background.jpg")));
                        setVisible(true);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                        //whatever you mean by "null state"
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Where can I put that?

Comment: It needs access to the jLabel3 of course, so wherever you'd usually add a Listener of some kind. For example, do this in the ru() method, instead of setting icons, etc.

Comment: Err.. Like this `public void ru(){` `jLabel3.addMouselistener(newMouseAdapter() { @.......... }); }'

Comment: So.. What should I do?